# AIC and BIC in GEE

Tags: model, goodness-of-fit, aic, generalized-estimating-equations, bic

Can I apply Akaike’s information criterion (AIC) and Quasi-likelihood under the independence model information criterion (QIC) in GEE?

Answer (score 2):

The AIC does not exist for GEE models, because AIC is calculated from the likelihood and GEE models are not derived from a likelihood. Similarly the BIC does not exist for GEE models.

Instead, the QIC was developed based on a quasi-likehood. The QIC can be used for model comparison. However, when the mean model is mispecified the hypothesis tests and confidence intervals from the selected model can perform poorly, so it is recommended to be cautions in your use of the QIC. The QIC is discussed in these references:

Pan, W. (2001), Akaike's Information Criterion in Generalized Estimating Equations. Biometrics, 57: 120-125. https://doi.org/10.1111/j.0006-341X.2001.00120.x

Hardin, J.W. and Hilbe, J.M. (2003), Generalized Estimating Equations, Chapman & Hall/CRC: New York.

Wang, Y., Murphy, O., Turgeon, M., Wang, Z., Bhatnagar, S. R., Schulz, J., and Moodie, E. E. M. (2015) The perils of quasi-likelihood information criteria. STAT, 4: 246– 254. https://doi.org/10.1002/sta4.95

Comment: If this is so, how can I check the model adequacy (Goodness-of-fit) in GEE estimation?

Comment: @MisganL.Liben Hardin and Hilbe's book has a chapter on model diagnostics and a section on goodness of fit. They give further references on variations of Proportional Reduction in Variation, Concordance Correlation, and a Chi-Sq Goodness of Fit Test. I'd suggest looking there as a start.